# Error when using Azimuth and Distance plugin

Tags: qgis-3

I've use Azimuth and Distance Plugin in the past and it worked with an earlier version of Qgis.  It even kind of worked this morning.  I realized I had the incorrect active layer.  I've closed the project and reinstalled the Plugin.  However[image], I still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have the completely correct answer.  Instead of using the active layer.  I used the Memory layer.  That allowed me to complete the drawing.  When I hit the Draw button it brought up a temporary scratch layer, and the Plugin drew the shape on the scratch layer.  I was then able to convert the shape to a polygon and put it on the correct layer.